# Upgrading memory to 32GB on MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, memory, macbook-pro

I would like to know whether it's possible to upgrade memory to 32GB with new MacBook Pro which I'm planning to by 2017 model cause of my MBP Mid-2012 does not work well with trackpad. But, Genius bar can not find where is wrong. So, I'm investigating about it to get 2017 model. I know there is no MacBook Pro is supported the size officially. But, Mid-2012 is supported until 16GB unofficially. So, I wonder it might be There is a way. If I could know I would appreciated. Please kindly advice me.

What is it for:

1. Run Windows 2016 AD on VMWare fusion
2. Run Windows 2012 AD on VMWare fusion
3. Run Windows 10 on VMWare fusion
4. Android Development
5. MS Office 2016
6. 3D CAD software

Comment: [MacBook Pro: How to remove or install memory](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165) as with anything unofficial you won't find official confirmation on it working. [Can I upgrade my 2011 MacBook Pro with 16GB?](https://superuser.com/questions/577423/can-i-upgrade-my-2011-macbook-pro-with-16gb?rq=1)

Comment: The current MacBook Pros have soldered RAM which cannot be changed at all.

Comment: @Seth, Thank you for the information and I confirmed I can replace the memory to 16GB on my Mid-2012. I gave up to buy 2017 model.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thank you for the information. Now, I understand the current MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know whether it's possible to upgrade memory to 32GB
>   with new MacBook Pro which I'm planning to by it cause of my MBP
>   Mid-2012 does not work well with trackpad. But, Genius bar can not
>   find where is wrong.

I assume you are talking about the new 2017 MacBook Pro laptops.  If you are then they have RAM soldered onto the motherboard.

> In both units, the processor, RAM, and flash memory are still soldered
>   to the logic board.

[Almost No New Hardware in the 2017 MacBook or MacBook Pro](https://ifixit.org/blog/9185/2017-apple-laptop/)